# How to create a filter for only parameters on a string

Tags: c#, angularjs, filtering

There is existing code that has a translate filter.
So, if the RESX file entry is "MyPhrase" (key) and the entry for US English is "This is my phrase with parameter: {0} and another {1}." and for Spanish is "Esta es mi frase con parámetro: {0} y otro {1}."

Basically, what it does it takes
**{{"MyPhrase" | translate}}** and picks the language and does the replacement parameters (html) for example:

```
{{"MyPhrase" | translate: "something" : "something else"}}
```

This is working fine and is not the issue.

What I am trying to do is either another filter or some way to do something on the replaceable parameters only.

For example, if I do

```
{{"MyPhrase" | translate: "something" : "something else" | uppercase}}
```

The entire phrase is uppercase, instead of just the 2 parameters

What I would like to do is something to the effect of

```
{{"MyPhrase" | translate: "something" | uppercase : "something else" | InitCaps}}
```

And end up with

> This is my phrase with parameter: SOMETHING and another Something
> Else.

Basically, I might have some common words/phrases like

"You have added an item to your {0}"
or simply "{0}"
or "Your {0} is empty".

So, I might use for one client "Recycle Bin" and another "Trash" (just examples, fyi).

For some cases, I would want "Your recycle bin is empty"
and for others "Recycle Bin" (initial caps), etc.

and for the other client, "Your trash is empty" and "Trash".

So, I am open to suggestions as the best way to handle parameters, filters, or other means to accomplish my goal, it doesn't have to be exactly as I stated, just anything that works...

Comment: I don't use resx for this, I just use a sqlite database or a service, work with a constant and n fields. Better even, a non sql database. Then String.Format(_code_,parameters as arrays)

Comment: I cannot change how my company does things with RESX files. I need a solution for my question, not completely change everything.

Comment: That's why I made a comment and not an answer.